# Problems with img src and template pages Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am building a `Wordpress` website from HTML/CSS/JS templates i made earlier. However this is my first time using it and im really struggling. There are plenty of resources and solutions however none seem to be working for me, for example; one tutorial pointed out you could create template pages if you go into your `management screen > pages > add new > page attributes > template`. But under page attributes is only "order" although it does claim there should be a template bit if you click help.

I've managed to link my stylesheet but none of my images are appearing. They are all in a folder named images within my theme directory.

In my external stylesheet i have:

```
body{
    background:url("images/subfolder/image01.jpg");
}
```

I have also tried:

```
body{
    background-image:url("images/subfolder/image.jpg");
}
```

In my html I have:

```
<img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/subfolder/image02.png" alt="DESCRIPTION" />
```

I have also tried:

```
<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/subfolder/image02.png" alt="DESCRIPTION" />
```

I can't seem to get any of these up.

Comment: Hey, as it stands this question has a very vague title ("Developing with Wordpress"). In fact, it's not really a question as it currently stands. Maybe you could make it a little more specific? Stack Overflow works best when questions asked are clear and specific.

Comment: i've explained the problems im having, the main ones being even though it's picking the stylesheet up its not picking images up and im not sure how to convert my html template into a wordpress page template. and i thought the broad title explained the broadness of my problems

Comment: This is a Q&A site, rather than a general forum, the idea being that someone who has the same problem you're having will be able to find your question + its solution in future. Unless you phrase your questions more specifically then that can't happen. "Developing with Wordpress" isn't a question, and as a heading it could cover a huge number of questions other than the one you're asking! Check out the help section for lots of helpful guidelines about the best ways to ask questions here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the deal:) Your folder structure **"must"** look like this

-Yourtheme Folder

index.php

style.css

page.php

single.php

...other files
  
    -images (images folder)
  
    -js (js folder)

So if you are developing a theme full image path will not help you much because you simply don't know how will your clients domain look, like it can be `http://www.mydomain.com/somefolder/` but it can also be `http://www.mydomain.com/somefolder/subfolder/anothersubfolder` so to access your images use relative paths like this:
`background-image:url('../images/myimage.jpg');` that way images will work no matter how your domain path will look.

Now to templates:)

In order to wordpress recognize that you are having a template create a file and name it **mycooltemplate.php** (you can name it however you want)
Your first line inside your template file must read something like this:

```
<?php /*Template name: This is my cool template*/   
?>
```

That way wordpress will know that you are using a template and you can access it inside

```
management screen > pages > add new > page attributes > template
```

So to give a real world example let's create our first template shall we?
We will now create an simple **archive** template.

Open your text editor and add this code

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: My Cool Archives Template
*/
get_header(); ?>

<div id="container">
<div id="content" role="main">

    <?php the_post(); ?>
    <h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>

    <?php get_search_form(); ?>

    <h2>Archives by Month:</h2>
    <ul>
        <?php wp_get_archives('type=monthly'); ?>
    </ul>

    <h2>Archives by Subject:</h2>
    <ul>
         <?php wp_list_categories(); ?>
    </ul>

        </div><!-- #content -->
            </div><!-- #container -->

            <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
            <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Save it as archives.php (name it however you want) and upload it to your theme folder. So now your folders should look like this:

-Yourtheme Folder

index.php

style.css

page.php

single.php

archives.php (your first template yeeey!!)

...other files
  
    -images (images folder)
  
    -js (js folder)

Hope this helps...

Comment: AHA!!!! i see!! thank you so much that makes so much more sense the template is now viewable via dashboard!!

Comment: quick question regarding templates if you can help; i've created my 2 custom template pages (temp01, temp02) which displays perfectly as i want it to in the default template, but when i use those templates myself - everything is fine except the content wrapper in the middle of the page which is squishy and looks as though its been forced to the left side rather than across the page? any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying the full path to the themes directory from your web root.

eg. `/wp-content/themes/[yourtheme]/images/subfolder/image01.jpg`

Comment: With the initial slash?

Comment: the full path is definately correct too as the image appears if i directly enter the path in my browser

Answer (score 0):

The image paths should work in your CSS but in your HTML/PHP you will need to use something like

```
<img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?> /images/subfolder/image02.png" />
```

Comment: I use it often because I am developing in child themes. If you use `bloginfo('template_directory)' then this will take you to the directory of the template and if you are using a child theme then it will take you to the parent theme.

Comment: what is your site url?

Comment: it's just on local host. i can view my page on localhost/WEBSITE, image src tried for your solution was <img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>http://localhost/WEBSITE/wp-content/themes/THEMENAME/TEMPLATES/IMAGES/SUBFOLDER/IMAGE02.png" alt="Home" />  and <img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/IMAGES/SUBFOLDER/IMAGE02.png" alt="Home" />  i've caps my own titled folders just to make it a bit clearer. thanks

Comment: You can use the dev tools in chrome to see where the path is pointing to.